# Remove the selected option from the choice field in admin panel

Tags: django, django-2.1

I want to reduce the choice option in the admin panel if it is selected once.

admin.py

```py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    LOC = [('op1', 'op1'), ('op2', 'op2'),...]

    location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LOC)


class DataModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
    list_display = ('location',)
    search_fields = ['location']

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['location']


admin.site.register(DataModel, DataModelAdmin)
```

model.py

```py
class DataModel(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location
```

I am trying to do but it removes the selected option on restarting the server

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  You are trying to remove an option without service/server restart or what?

Comment: can you explain more with an example?

Comment: In `DataModel` I have a unique field in location. So once I select the option `op2` from `LOC = [('op1', 'op1'), ('op2', 'op2'),...]` then the next time `LOC` have these option only `[('op1'), ('op3'), ('op4'),...]`

Comment: Yes @tukan, I am trying to remove an option without service/server restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly you want to remove the object's location from the field choices...

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    LOC = [('op1', 'op1'), ('op2', 'op2')]

    location = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['location'].choices = [
                choice for choice in self.LOC
                if choice[0] != self.instance.location
            ]
        else:
            self.fields['location'].choices = self.LOC
```

Actually on second read maybe you're looking for a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)?

```
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class LocationFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'location'
    parameter_name = 'location'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        locations = DataModel.objects.values_list('location', flat=True)
        return locations

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(location=self.value())
```

Then add `list_filter = (LocationFilter,)` to your admin class.

Answer (score 1):

By adding **init** to the `MyModelForm` class, you can remove the option in a choice field

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    item = [i.location for i in DataModel.objects.all()]
    if self.instance.id:
        item.remove(self.instance.location)
    self.fields['location'].choices = [(i, j) for i, j in self.LOC if i not in item]
```